# Oracle Audit - DDL/DML not on. System Events on. How to turn all on?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ddl, audit, dml

Afternoon everyone,

I currently have a Oracle DB issue. I have Oracle Auditing on (AUDIT_TRAIL set to db). However the only information being captured is the System Events (log on, off).

From the Oracle 10g2 documenation (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Auditing_10gR2.php) I notice that there are 3 audit options, however I cannot figure out how to turn the other 2 on.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your question, but I know that the link you describe as "the Oracle documentation" is a third-party advice site.  [This is the Oracle 10g documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage).  Specifically, [here is the documentation on auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/auditing.htm#DBSEG125).  There you will find the answers you seek (at least I assume you will).